# Why isn't index / table renaming supported in DynamoDB?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

From what I can tell, renaming an existing table or index is not possible on DynamoDB. Is there any reason why? I don't understand why it isn't a simple task.

(Alternatively, if it is possible to rename either, please let me know!)

Comment: Lacking this support, I wonder what the shortest path is to renaming an existing index.  I'm new to DynamoDB.  Do I need to re-write all of the items in my primary table to have DynamoDB fill out the new index, or is there some more direct way to have it do so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Absent an official explanation from AWS, there is no objective answer that can be given for the reason why this isn't possible.  The reason is because that's how they designed it, and nobody can say more with any authority.

But we can come to some reasonable conclusions, based on the fact that few tasks are "simple" in distributed systems.

Changing the name of a table or index is an operation that would either need to be instantaneous, or require the entire table to be frozen and locked while the operation occurs.  No operations could be in progress when the rename occurs, because they'd potentially be invalid -- referencing the new name too early, or the old name too late.   And the entire application would need to be updated at the same time.

Relational databases have an easier time allowing renames because they are a single thing in a single place -- the index is on a table on a master server, and the server can lock the table metadata (waiting for the lock while queries complete, then preventing further queries while the change is made, then releasing the lock).

Your DynamoDB table does not have a master server.  Your tables are transparently sharded across multiple partitions across multiple servers, and each of these has multiple replica/peers in other availability zones in the region.  It's a highly distributed system.  Coordinating an operation across all these layers is a complex proposition -- not impossible, possibly not even impractical, but requiring additional layers of complexity to accomplish something that is rarely needed... high cost, low payoff.

It would be seen as unacceptable in many cases if tables or indexes had a state -- similar to the [`Backfilling`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/SQLtoNoSQL.Indexes.html) state during initial index creation -- that blocked their use while the necessary background tasks performed a rename.   The likely exceptions would be for small tables and tables not used in production... and those are the cases that would be the lowest value scenarios for such a feature.

Comment: Your writing style is immaculate

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue a week ago and there is only one way to achieve this. Currently, you'll have to create a new table with the new name and drop/delete the old one.

I spent the past week working in DynamoDB for the first time and realized there are many features which are lacking in DynamoDB for instance importing data from a csv file is also not supported within the AWS console.

Comment: I consider the lack of importers to be a feature, not a bug.  I see this as a slippery slope leading to code bloat and a growing testing nightmare.  Once you support reading from one external data source, then where do you draw the line?  This sort of thing is better left to the realm of companion tools, be they developed at Amazon or elsewhere.  The core Dynamo developers have nothing over the rest of us in terms of developing such tools.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the name while creating a backup. When you restore the backup, the table will have the name you filled.

Answer (score 0):

The best and easiest way is to create a new table and drop the existing one. 
Also the while creating backups it can take new names and when you restore that it will be with new names. 
The main concern behind the dynamodb is cost, and that is why few features are missing which we are used to have with a normal RDMS system.